# Can't connect to web service in Java due to CORS

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, angularjs

I have created a filter like this and I configured it in the web.xml. I manage to retrieve data with simple GET methods, but when trying to POST a new resource it fails. I am using AngularJS and I get this in the console. I haven't fully understood what CORS is, but from what I have read it seems like there is a "pre-flight" request (OPTIONS method?). I don't know what I miss, how can I fix it? This is the error that I get:

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type");

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting to a different domain? You can set it up but this looks like it's a mistake. `localhost` is a very strange domain to be posting from.

Comment: JBoss port 8080, Apache web server port 80.

Comment: Are you using $http or $resource?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan At the moment $http, but I can change if I have too?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some settings in you web.xml. Here is a link that should help you http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html